# Conditional Procedure oracle Pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a procedure with the following condition

```
$$
select 'Y'
     from dual
    where exists
             (select 'Y'
                from pa_expenditure_items_all paei, pa_expenditures_all pae
               where     paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id
                     and pae.incurred_by_person_id =&person_id
                     and paei.cost_distributed_flag = 'N')
$$
```

if the condition returns Null then it should display an error message and then an error.
for the error message I am using dbms_output.put_line and for error I am using exception then also can anyone help me out of these

I am trying these

```
 create or replace procedure validate_terminate
declare
l_yes out varchar2 (1);
null_found exception;
is
begin
   select 'Y'
     into l_yes
     from dual
    where exists
             (select 'Y'
                from pa_expenditure_items_all paei, pa_expenditures_all pae
               where     paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id
                     and pae.incurred_by_person_id =&person_id
                     and paei.cost_distributed_flag = 'N');

   if l_yes is null
   then
      dbms_output_put_line ('Condition is not met'); 
   raise null_found;
   end if;
   exception 
   when null_found then 
     dbms_output_put_line('CANNOT PROCESS TERMINATE');
end;
```

Comment: Procedures cannot prompt a user for input when they run.  If you want this to run for a particular `person_id`, you'd normally declare a parameter and let the caller handle passing in the value.  Is that what you want to do?  Or do you want to make this an anonymous PL/SQL block and have the client tool (`SQL*Plus` or something else) prompt you for the value when the block is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a procedure use `IS` instead of `DECLARE` - don't use both.

You don't need to check if `l_yes` is null - if your select returns 0 rows, it'll automatically raise a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception. Just catch that.

You don't need to select a second time (from dual). The first select works fine.

Don't put `out` after `l_yes` in the declaration. It's just `l_yes varchar2(1);`.

It's `dbms_output.put_line`.

Use bind variable `:person_id` instead of substitution variable `&person_id`

```
set define off
create or replace procedure validate_terminate
is
   l_yes varchar2(1);
begin
   select 'Y'
     into l_yes
     from dual
    where exists
             (select 'Y'
                from pa_expenditure_items_all paei, pa_expenditures_all pae
               where     paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id
                     and pae.incurred_by_person_id = :person_id
                     and paei.cost_distributed_flag = 'N');

   exception 
   when NO_DATA_FOUND then
     dbms_output.put_line ('Condition is not met');  
     dbms_output.put_line('CANNOT PROCESS TERMINATE');
     raise;
end;
/
```

Comment: HI Kfinity Iam getting these error now Error(11,53): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'PERSON_ID'Error(11,53): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'PERSON_ID'

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declaration and exception handling is improper.

Try below code:

```
create or replace procedure validate_terminate
declare
l_yes varchar2(1);
--null_found exception;
is
begin
   select 'Y'
     into l_yes
     from pa_expenditure_items_all paei, pa_expenditures_all pae
   where paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id
     and pae.incurred_by_person_id =&person_id
     and paei.cost_distributed_flag = 'N';
   exception 
   when no_data_found then 
     dbms_output_put_line ('Condition is not met'); 
     dbms_output_put_line('CANNOT PROCESS TERMINATE');
end;
/
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL is not an interactive programming language. It is a tool for materialising SQL and related code to be called from other clients. It is those clients which handle user input and other UI things.

So the idiomatic way of writing your procedure would be to pass the PERSON_ID as a parameter ....

```
create or replace procedure validate_terminate
   (p_person_id in pa_expenditure_items_all.incurred_by_person_id%type ) 
is
  l_yes out varchar2 (1);
  null_found exception;
is
begin
   select 'Y'
   into l_yes
   from dual
   where exists
             (select 'Y'
                from pa_expenditure_items_all paei
                     ,pa_expenditures_all pae
               where paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id
                 and pae.incurred_by_person_id =p_person_id
                 and paei.cost_distributed_flag = 'N');

   if l_yes is null
   then
      dbms_output_put_line ('Condition is not met'); 
   raise null_found;
   end if;
exception 
   when null_found then 
     dbms_output_put_line('CANNOT PROCESS TERMINATE');
end;
```

Then you call the procedure like this (assuming you want to use SQL*Plus, as your choice of notation suggests):

```
exec validate_terminate(&person_id)
```

Note I've assumed PERSON_ID is numeric; if it's a string you'll need to quote it.